# close a shiny app on a click

Tags: css, onclick, shiny

At the moment the app ends when the user clicks on a button `Q`. I would like this app to end when the user clicks `Quit` *on the navbar*.  Unfortunately I can't figure out how to do this. Will be thankful for any help!

EDIT:
It would be great to know how to shift `Quit` tab to the right :)

```
ui <- shinyUI(navbarPage(title = "Test", 
        tabPanel(title = "Content",
                 actionButton(inputId = "quit", label = "Quit")
        ),
        tabPanel(title = "Quit", icon = icon("circle-o-notch"))
        )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output) {
  observe({
    if (input$quit == 1) stopApp()
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution for your problem is to create an id for the navbar, with that, you can call observer like you did but changing the input. The only problem is to identificate that you need to create a new id for the navbarPage.

```
shinyApp(
ui = navbarPage(title = "Test", id="navbar", 
                         tabPanel(title = "Content"),
                         tabPanel(title = "Quit", value="stop", icon = icon("circle-o-notch"))
), #Close UI

server = function(input,output,session) {
  observe({
    if (input$navbar == "stop") 
        stopApp()
  })
} #Close server 

) #Close shinyApp
```