# Rscript slave call doesn't exit properly

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Desktop Entry that calls a shiny app.

Here's my desktop entry

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Comment=App
Name=App
Exec=/usr/bin/Rscript -e "shiny::runApp('~/raspberry_IP/app.R', launch.browser=TRUE)"
Icon=/home/path/to/logo/rpi_logo.png
Terminal=false
Categories=Utility
StartupNotify=true
```

This runs well and the `Shiny` application works as expected. However, when I close my browser tab, I see the process is still running.

I am running this application from `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS`.

If I change my `terminal=false` to `terminal=true`. I see that the output of my terminal freezes (the app no longer updates, hence no diagnostic printing). But the terminal is still active (which makes sense given the process is still running). I can `CTRL+C` out of it to kill it from my terminal, but that's not the desired user behavior.

I see some strategies to stop the app using `stopApp()` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32529215/close-a-shiny-app-on-a-click). This strategy uses a separate action button to kill the app, so the user has to "manually" stop it. This might work, but I believe it's natural for the user to try to close the tab or Browser (and there's no way for them to know the process is still running, unless they check).

Using this on the `server` side, does kill the process, but it's recommended against (see [here](https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/tree/master/auto-kill-app)).

```
session$onSessionEnded(stopApp)
```

In this case, because my app is running on a local machine, I think I could potentially get away with this (there is only one user at a time), but I was wondering whether there's better practice to implement.